# Toggle between three images onclick?

Tags: jquery, css, image, toggle

I have 3 images of squirrels:

```
<img src="images/SquirrelFull.jpeg"  class="squirrel">
<img src="images/SquirrelName.jpeg"  class="squirrel">
<img src="images/SquirrelEmpty.jpeg"  class="squirrel">
```

I want to put them on top of one another and "toggle" through them with a click.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't feel like using a plugin, here's an example of how you could toggle through your squirrels:

http://jsfiddle.net/jAMzV/

Basically I put the squirrels in a parent container, and hide them all except the one with the class `default`. Then you bind a click-event on the squirrels which does the following:

Hide the one clicked, which is the only one visible
Check if there's a next element in line, if there's not, pick the first one and show that, otherwise show the next one.

This way it loops over and over.

Comment: Even though I know your code is correct, it still doesn't work for some crazy reason.  The css and html work fine when I tweek them, but I get nothing from the js.  I have a link in the head to `      <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>       
`  I don't know what is up, but thank you!

Comment: WOW!  I finally figured it out.  It was some crazy little invisible error that happened when I copied and pasted your code directly into Dreamweaver.  It totally works now.  Phew!! There's 7 hours of my life I'll never see again.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQueryCycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin. Is easy to learn and powerfull... You'll find all information you need in their page

Here, i think its that you want:

```
<h1>Example</h1>
<div id="s1" class="pics">
                <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
<div class="nav">(Click on image for next slide)</div>
<pre>
<code class="mix">$('#s1').cycle({
        fx:     'slideY',
        speed:  300,
        next:   '#s1',
        timeout: 0 });
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take jCarousel: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html

For this you only have to write in JavaScript this:

```
    $(function(){

/*#mycarousel is the ID from the ul list*/

    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        "wrap": 'circular',
        "scroll": 1
    });
```

an in html you don't have to forget this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then you just can create your slide with the right classes

```
<div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" id="pictureslide">
  <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" id="pic" style='position: relative;'>
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal">
        <li class='jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal' id='jcarousel-item-1'>
            <img src="images/SquirrelFull.jpeg"  class="squirrel">
            </li>
        <li class='jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal' id="jcarousel-item-2" >
            <img src="images/SquirrelName.jpeg"  class="squirrel">
            </li>
        <li class='jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal' id="jcarousel-item-3" >
        <img src="images/SquirrelEmpty.jpeg"  class="squirrel">
        </li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
 <!-- Here are the arrows-->   
    <div class="jcarousel-prev jcarousel-prev-horizontal" style="display:'block'">
        <a class="controls prev" href="#"><img id="arrow-left" src="pic/arrow_left.png" alt="arrow-left" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal" style="display:'block'">
        <a class="controls next" href="#"><img id="arrow-right" src="pic/arrow_right.png" alt="arrow-right"/></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fzxgd/1/

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give one more solution...
Working...

```js
$('img').click(function () {
  $('img').each(function(){
    var classes = ['icon','icon1','icon2'];
    this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length];
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 30%; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }
 
 .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  

 }
 .icon1  {
  position: relative;
  display: none;

 }
 .icon2  {
  position: relative;
  display: none;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Little Twitter Buttons</title>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<img class="icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/9FEVXE2.png" alt="*" height="80" width="80"/>
<img class="icon1" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZ1w6Qt.png" alt="*" height="80" width="80"/>
<img class="icon2" src="http://i.imgur.com/TRWB1qO.png" alt="*" height="80" width="80"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```